# Why is the retrieve method not working here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

Lets say there are 3 divs (there can be thousands of such divs) having same class inside a parent div.

Each of them have some text which dynamically changes. When I try to save their content using localstorage and retreive them the first div's html is copied in the other 2 divs.

HTML

```
 <div class="parent">
     <div class="child">*dynamically changing text</div>
     <div class="child">*dynamically changing text</div>
     <div class="child">*dynamically changing text</div>
 </div>
```

Script to retreive the content

```
if (localStorage.getItem('counter') === null) 
{
    $(".parent > div").each(function()
    {
        localStorage.setItem('counter', $(this).find(".child").html());
    }); 
    var counter = 0;
} 
else 
{
    $(".parent > div").each(function()
    {
        $(this).find(".child").html(localStorage.getItem('counter'));
        var counter = localStorage.getItem('counter');
    });
}
```

Script to set the content

```
$(".parent > div").each(function()
{
    localStorage.setItem('counter', $(this).find(".child").html());
});
```

Now let's say that the contents change as follows:
1st child : 4
2nd child : 5
3rd child : 10

Now when I retrieve all the 3 child divs are showing 4. How to fix this?

Comment: `counter` is a string, and it's the key, so you're overwriting that index in localStorage every time. Is it really a good idea to store the contents of thousands of elements in localStorage ?

Answer (score 2):

> When I try to save their content using localstorage and retreive them the first div's html is copied in the other 2 divs.

Well, of course it is — that's what your code is explicitly doing. You have only **one** `counter` in local storage, and you repeatedly overwrite it in your `each` loop for saving, and you repeatedly re-retrieve and apply it in your `each` loop for getting.

Use **different** names (`counter0`, `counter1`, etc.) to store the text of different divs in local storage. You can get them from the first argument to `each`, which is the index of the element you're visiting.

Retrieving, and creating `counterX` if it doesn't exist:

```
$(".parent > div").each(function(index)
{
    var counter = localStorage.getItem('counter' + index);
    if (counter === null)
    {
        // Create
        localStorage.getItem('counter' + index, $(this).find(".child").html());
    }
    else
    {
        // Use
        $(this).find(".child").html(counter);
    }
});
```

Setting:

```
$(".parent > div").each(function(index)
{
    localStorage.setItem('counter' + index, $(this).find(".child").html());
});
```

Comment: Okay I get it now. But now how to auto create a counter for each div.

Comment: @AnupamRam: What do you mean by "auto create"?

Comment: What if there are hundred of divs? It won't be possible to manually create counter0, counter1....uptill counter100. How to auto-create all these counters?

Comment: @AnupamRam: Why wouldn't it be possible? But take a look at the code I've added, it may help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- Either use different `localStorage` items for every `div` element, same as T.J. Crowder said.
- Or compose an `array` of all the text and save it in one `localStorage` item.

Use `index` in the jQuery `.each()` function to set and get the localStorage item if you go for the first option mentioned above.

```
$(".child").each(function( index ) {
  localStorage.setItem('counter'+index, $(this).html());
});
```

With this code, you can guess what code you will write while `getting` the item.

*Readup*: [`.each()` | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: *"Same as T.J. Crowder said..."* Then why repeat it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, I wanted to add the code that would introduce him to `index` in the `.each()` loop. Thats how I wanted to make my answer different than yours.